# Using Arrays in Other Classes

Tags: java, arrays, class

In a program I've been writing, there's a problem I've been having with an array.

In one class, an array is created:

```
public class pixel {
    public boolean[] pixelAvailability = new boolean[100];
}
```

This class also has other methods that have been tested by themselves.

There's another class that has a method which will print 100 characters, either spaces, or a letter 'b'. The code I've written to do this is:

```
public class printing {
    pixel pixel = new pixel();

    public void print() {
        for (int y = 10; y >= 1; y--) {
            for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
                if (pixel.pixelCheck(x,y)) {
                    System.out.print("b");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

The "pixel.pixelCheck" method used here can be ignored. It's been tested and I've confirmed it works properly.  It will simply take two integer inputs, 'x' and 'y', and return whether or not a corresponding value in the pixelAvailability array is true or false (returning a boolean).

The next method used is:

```
public class walls {
    pixel pixel = new pixel();

    public void walls() {
        for (int y = 1; y >= 10; y++) {
            pixel.pixelAssign(1,y,true);
        }
    // Other methods...
}
```

The method used in this class, "pixelAssign", takes two values, 'x' and 'y', and will find it's corresponding value in the pixelAvailability array, and change it to either true or false.

The last class in my main class:

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printing printing = new printing;
        pixel pixel = new pixel;
        walls walls = new walls;

        walls.walls();
        printing.print();
}
```

I've just created instances of the classes using the same names to avoid confusion.

When I run the program, all I get is 10 lines of spaces, with 10 spaces each. I can't get a single 'b' character to appear. I've tried switching a value in the array to true in the "printing" class right before it prints, which did work, and a 'b' appeared! However, the "walls" method used doesn't work.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your `pixel` class is missing all the mentioned methods. Also please use Uppercase names for classes.

Comment: `new pixel;` you forgot to call the constructor: `new pixel();`. Note that class names in java should always start with an uppercase letter, so `Pixel` instead.

Comment: @Ben I think it is not missing the methods, OP said "*This class also has other methods that have been tested by themselves.*". I think he's just not showing them to us. Would be better to include something like `// Other methods...` in the code then.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] (emphasis on **complete**), otherwise it will be hard to find the bug.

Comment: @Zabuza ah I did not see that, my bad. Still it's kinda hard to evaluate if the `println` happens only when a missing method returns true (which does kinda lead to the idea that the method might not be returning true...) (even if they say it's "guaranteed to work")

Comment: If you are missing methods, the code won't even compile. It is hard to help you with your problem if you don't create a [mcve]. In the best case this would be a code that I can directly copy into my IDE and hit run. Your current code is **not complete**.

Comment: You should also practice debugging small programs. Add some `System.out.println(...)` statements to see what your method does. Since you don't get `"b"` in the output, the `if (pixel.pixelCheck(x,y))` condition always evaluated to `false`. I can't tell you why, your question doesn't include the code necessary to tell that. If you use an IDE, you may use its debugger. A debugger can execute code line by line and pause the program between every line. You can then view the current state of all variables and exactly see how the program executes.